# Is it possible to override Android PackageManager::clearAllApplicationUserData?

Tags: android

I have a task that clears all user data from my Android platform. I achieve this clearing by calling the package manager's clearAllApplicationUserData, then rebooting.

Is it possible to provide custom behavior for this operation? I have an app that is not cleaning up database cursors after the reboot.

Note: I am not a 3rd party developer. The platform I am working on is custom.

Answer (score 0):

As a 3rd party Application Developer you cant..!!!

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I am not a 3rd party developer. My applications are system apps.

Answer (score 0):

why not to delete the databases using  `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);` ?

Comment: That would be ok within the app itself, but it would be a lot cleaner to override the handling of clearAllApplicationUserData.